# Асинхронный торнадо

Tags: python, tornado

Есть простой http обработчик

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Как сделать асинхронное выполнение,что бы при одновременных запросах, вместо простоя в 5 сек, программа начинала обрабатывать следующий запрос

Comment: Попробуйте глянуть [офф-сайт](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените `MainHandler` на

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
        await tornado.gen.sleep(5)
        self.write("Hello, world")
```

либо, если tornado запущен на asyncio

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        self.write("Hello, world")
```

Пример с executor

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
        await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 1)
        self.write("Hello, world")
```

тут вместо `time.sleep` будет ваша функция, а вместо 1 - значение которое вы в неё передадите.

Comment: @eri спасибо за правку)

Comment: на самом деле более полезная часть там про экзекуторы

Comment: Так, а если вместо sleep у меня стоит функция которая ждет ответа от сервера в течении 5 секунд

Comment: @МихаилМалышев дополнил ответ

Comment: @МихаилМалышев Когда участник [получает хороший ответ на свой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), он может отметить его как верный – «принять». После принятия ответа слева от него появляется галочка зелёного цвета.

Comment: @5c0rp а есть возможность вернуть значение выполняемой функции и сохранить в переменную

Comment: @МихаилМалышев `result = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 1)` попробуйте так